# I have changed the value of char *a[9] in function，then I use them for the first time ,they get garbled。

Tags: c

I want to changed the value of code_array in function HuffmanTree_code.
when I run the HuffmanTree_code(HuffmanTree T,char *code_array[M]),debug show the right result as image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqVfy.png),then I want to use the value of code_array,when I print the first char value of code_array for the first time ,the rest of code_array get garbled as image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGAJI.png).Please help。
PS:if you want the whole program ,please tell me.
PSS:What I learn is the Huffman coding,if you have some solutions,please commit,please,please。

```
void HuffmanTree_code(HuffmanTree T,char *code_array[M])
{
    char code[M] = {0,0,0};
    char onecode[M];

    char code_aa[N][M];
    int length = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int t = 0;
    int cop = 0;
    for ( m = 0; m < N; m++)
    {
        j = M - 2;
        i = m;
        while (T[i].parent != 0)
        {
            if (T[T[i].parent].lchild == i)
                code[j--] = '0';
            else
                code[j--] = '1';
            i = T[i].parent;
        }
        length = M - 2 - j;
        strcpy(onecode, code+j+1);  
        strcpy(code_aa[m], onecode);
        code_array[m] = code_aa[m];
        printf("%s\n", code_aa[m]);
    }
}
int main()
{
//code
HuffmanTree_code(T1,code);
printf("%s\n", code[0]);
}
```

Debug image:
[run the HuffmanTree_code(T1,code);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqVfy.png) 
[run the printf("%s\n", code[0])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGAJI.png)

Comment: `code_array[m] = code_aa[m];` That is not going to work. `code_aa` is a local variable and goes out of scope (becomes invalid) as soon as the function exits. So storing a reference to it in `code_array` and accessing it outside the function will result in Undefined Behaviour. Need to allocate dynamic mem for the `code_array` pointers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always provide code that is actually compileable. What is `T`, what is `code`? See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: What kaylum wrote is correct and is causing your problem. You can replace that assignment with `code_array[m] = strdup(code_aa[m]);`. And you need to free the memory when no longer in use.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks！Can you teach me how to allocate dynamic mem for the code_array pointers.I have tried like this ——code_array[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * M * M);   
 but it goes wrong.

Comment: @ Gerhardh sorry, I will notice

Comment: @ Gerhardh  Thanks! I slove the problem ,if i don't use the strdup(),how can l allocate dynamic mem for the code_array pointers? Can you teach me? Help

Comment: You need memory to hold the string and you need to copy it: `code_array[m] = malloc(strlen(code_aa[m])+1); strcpy(code_array[m], code_aa[m]);`. In C, the return value of `malloc` doesn't need to be casted to another pointer type. And as `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 in any implementation, you can drop that when calculating the size. Checking the return value for `NULL` wouldn't be a bad idea also.

Comment: @kaylum: Scope is not the issue and is not associated with function “exit.” Lifetime is the issue. The memory for `code_array` is released when execution of the function ends. Scope is **where** in **source code** an **identifier** is visible. Lifetime is **when** during **program execution** memory is reserved for an **object**.

Comment: @ Gerhardh Thanks！ I gradually understand ,thank you so much.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah you're right. I got the terminology wrong.